# bug investigation in browser rendering

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I have a strange CSS bug. My nice blue button with [semantic-ui](/questions/tagged/semantic-ui) renders neatly in the mobile phone and in the developer mode of a web browser. But not in the normal mode. What could be the problem?

Is my strategy best to try and make a MCVE, then the button works. Should I now try and validate the html then it validates with w3c but the buttons still don't render if I don't enable developer mode. It's the blue button to the right and I base my code on the [item example](http://semantic-ui.com/views/item.html) in the manual of semantic-ui.

[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: looks like it is overflowing from container can you show the link or fiddle??

Comment: the link is http://www.qlbusiness.com/usa if you enable developer mode, then the button will appear.

Comment: take the float:right rule off of the <div style="border: 10px solid Red;" class="ui right floated primary button">

Comment: @CarolMcKay Yes. The button displays if I set the float property to none: `<div style="float:none"; class="ui right floated primary button">`. Thanks.

Comment: Win! You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to advice you to remove this container class this is the reason such thing happening.

```
<section class="list_container">
                    <div class="container">
```

**This code should be**

```
<section class="list_container">
                    <div>
```

just remove this class no other changes 
thank you

Comment: That's just perfect :-)

Comment: Yeah! i know haha xD